# Why do JPEG images appear all smudged, with magenta yellow and cyan scattered over the image?

Tags: images, jpeg

I have noticed this for JPEG images only, not PNG. For example [these captcha images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK9U2.jpg). The skies don't appear clear and natural at all, they appear speckled with random magenta, yellow and cyan pixels. Why does this happen in JPEG images? Can someone explain what causes this?

Comment: Not a technical answer, but grain can result from the ISO used when taking the photo, and for JPEG files, additional noise may come from compression (JPEG compression is lossy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to the noise in the camera sensor and is stronger when a higher ISO setting is used.

It can happen in any kind of image format (including raw), but it happens more in JPEG-s (and less in PNG-s) because these kind of images are more likely to be stored in JPEG format. PNG-s are mostly used to store screenshots and computer-generated graphics, not photos.

The noise generated by JPEG compression looks different, see [this example](https://cscie12.dce.harvard.edu/lecture_notes/2009/20090304/slide51.html).

In this particular case (a captcha), I think a noisy image was choosen because it is poorly identified by image-recognition bots.

You may get better responses about noise in photos in the [Photography Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yuck, JPEG compression looks horrible. Why are images compressed like? Computers these days have dozens to hundreds of gigabytes, there is no point in lossless compression these days. But thanks, this answer was useful.

Comment: The compression in the example referenced in the article is extreme, just to show what compression artifacts look like. For more realistic compression ratios, see the examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Sample_photographs. The second image listed there (with Q=50) has a compression ratio of 15:1 and almost no visible differences from the highest quality image.